# PRISMA - How to filter the relation nested after m2m relation?

Tags: prisma, prisma-graphql

How to filter a relation nested after m2m relation?

Unfortunately as for 2022-11 in Prisma documentation there isn't any info about that.

Schema.prisma:

```
model Entity {
  id                 Int                @id @default(autoincrement())
  name               String
  service_entity_m2m ServiceEntityM2m[]

}
model Service {
  id                 Int                @id @default(autoincrement())
  service_entity_m2m ServiceEntityM2m[]

}
model ServiceEntityM2m {
  id         Int        @id @default(autoincrement())
  entity_id  Int
  entity     Entity     @relation(fields: [entity_id], references: [id])
  service_id Int
  service    Service    @relation(fields: [service_id], references: [id])
}
```

Schema.graphql:

```
  type Entity {
    id: ID!
    name: String
  }

  type Service {
    id: ID!
    service_entity_m2m: [ServiceEntityM2m]
  }

  type ServiceEntityM2m {
    id: ID!
    entity: Entity!
    service: Service!
  }
```

seeder:

// services

```
{
  id: 1
}
```

// service_entity_m2m:

```
{
  id: 1,
  service_id: 1,
  entity_id: 1
},
{
  id: 2,
  service_id: 1,
  entity_id: 2
}
```

// entities

```
{
  id: 1,
  name: "XYZ"
},
{
  id: 2,
  name: "Test"
}
```

This code:

```
context.prisma.service.findMany({
    where: { service_entity_m2m: { some: { entity: { name: { contains: "Test" } } } } },
    include: { service_entity_m2m: { include: { entity: true } } },
})
```

returns both entities:

```
[ 
  { 
    id: 1, 
    service_entity_m2m: 
    [
      { 
        id: 1, 
        entity: { 
          id: 1, 
          name: "XYZ" 
        } 
      },
      {
        id: 2, 
        entity: { 
          id: 2, 
          name: "Test" 
        } 
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

How to write a query that is going to return only one entity with the name "Test": ?

```
[ 
  { 
    id: 1, 
    service_entity_m2m: 
    [
      {
        id: 2, 
        entity: { 
          id: 2, 
          name: "Test" 
        } 
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Could you please share your schema file so that I can write a query which works for you?

Comment: @NurulSundarani I've edited the post and added schema.prisma in the beginning of it